# Sorting list of dictionaries with different keys by value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with one key and one value only. Keys are always different, value is float number. How do I sort it by value?

```
example_list = [{'c47-d75 d75-e6b e6b-ff1 ff1-6d6 6d6-e63 e63-80c': 292.1799470129255}, {'805-7fd': 185.56518334219}, {'805-dd3 dd3-088 088-dd3 dd3-80c': 368.5010685728143}, {'805-6b5': 145.897977770909}, {'77e-805 805-7fd': 326.693786870932}, {'323-83d': 131.71963170528})
```

The result should be sorted by value so the first item should be

```
{'805-dd3 dd3-088 088-dd3 dd3-80c': 368.5010685728143}
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

To sort the list based on the first value of the dictionary, pass a function to `sorted()` to extract the first value of the dictionary.

1. `d.values()` returns an iterable of the dictionary values
2. `iter()` generates an iterator of the dictionary values
3. Since there is only 1 dictionary value (by assumption), calling `next()` on the iterator returns the first (and only) value.

To sort by greatest to least value, pass the `reverse=True` keyword argument to `sorted()`.

```
def first_value(d):
    return next(iter(d.values()))

example_list = [{'c47-d75 d75-e6b e6b-ff1 ff1-6d6 6d6-e63 e63-80c': 292.1799470129255}, {'805-7fd': 185.56518334219}, {'805-dd3 dd3-088 088-dd3 dd3-80c': 368.5010685728143}, {'805-6b5': 145.897977770909}, {'77e-805 805-7fd': 326.693786870932}, {'323-83d': 131.71963170528}]

sorted_list = sorted(example_list, key=first_value, reverse=True)

print(sorted_list[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```py
>>> for d in sorted(example_list, key=lambda d: max(d.values()), reverse=True):
...     print(d)
...
{'805-dd3 dd3-088 088-dd3 dd3-80c': 368.5010685728143}
{'77e-805 805-7fd': 326.693786870932}
{'c47-d75 d75-e6b e6b-ff1 ff1-6d6 6d6-e63 e63-80c': 292.1799470129255}
{'805-7fd': 185.56518334219}
{'805-6b5': 145.897977770909}
{'323-83d': 131.71963170528}
```

This sorts by using the `max()` function on the values associated with each dictionary. Since there's only one value in each dictionary, it just returns that value.

Honest question, why have a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary with key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dictionary sorted by values as follows:

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(example_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse = True)}
```

Since you want the values sorted in descending order you should keep the parameter **reverse = True**, else for ascending order set it to **False**.